# Is there any way we can use Left join on non related **Tables** or **Entity** using their ID only ? in Criteria Builder

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, criteria

Is there any way we can use Left join on non related **Tables** or **Entity** using their ID only ? in Criteria Builder

```
class A (
   val id: UUID
   val message: String
)

class B (
  val id: UUID
  val a_id: UUID,
  val type: Boolean
)
```

is there any thing that can build like this using criteria builder ? or any suggestion ?

> Select a, b from A a left join B b on a.a_id = b.id

Comment: Object models should not have a surrogate key like `id` in them, but never mind that for now. "LEFT JOIN" is a database concept, not an object-oriented concept. Doing it in an object model is not a good fit. What is the relationship in entity terms you're trying to model? IOW, what is the real-world connection? Since an ID field has no meaning in the domain model, and can change arbitrarily without respect to domain semantics, it might be buggy to relate things based only on IDs. That said, if the ID is consistent with the natural keys and the relationship you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote from the book *Java Persistence with Hibernate*:

> JPA and Hibernate don’t support arbitrary outer joins without a mapped
>   entity association or collection.

For your requirement, you should fall back to native SQL.

Comment: do you mean nativeQuery?

Comment: Yes. EntityManager.createNativeQuery(). You might want to check ResultTransformer interface and @SqlResultSetMapping annotations. I am sure there are tutorials on internet about using native queries with JPA.

Comment: i see. have you ever encoutered this kind of error ? org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002;

Comment: i use this kind then query mutilple objects or entity in native query entityManager.createNativeQuery(native, Tuple::class.java)

Comment: I have never encountered this exception, but it seems like a problem with the dialect specified. Which SQL dialect did you specify in your persistence.xml? Or, in case of spring, how do you specify the dialect?